# Can I receive data from the server while using Google Cardboard API?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am new in Virtual Reality development.

I learned that Google Cardboard for Unity lets Android devices run Unity stuffs as an independent application.

But is it possible to communicate with the server using regular Java (ex: inside onCreate() method in MainActivity.java, via POST method) and run 3D VR stuffs at the same time?

For example, can I code so that the app receives some data from the server and apply changes to 3D objects which were created via Unity?

The part where Unity is not coding, but just a simple drag-and-drop interfaced development kit got me all confused. (confer to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vkRtsaP3co)

Comment: Do you want to make a Unity app for android, that utilizes VR and speaks with a server? Because all of that can be done within Unity (without Java, which would complicate things)

Comment: Yes. i want it to communicate with server just like a normal android app(using Java), but the only difference will be that the user will be seeing 3D stuffs, not the typical Android UI.

Comment: @K.Gkinis Would this be pretty complicated?

Comment: If you want to use the Android API for sockets etc from within Unity, then you have to create a unity android plugin (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html , http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15308/can-i-access-java-code-from-unity.html , https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/). That way, you can use Java code from Unity.

Comment: If on the other hand, you want a native apk, built with Java (like any other Java app), that uses Unity for rendering, then 1) I don't really know how to do that and I'm pretty sure that you can't do it with the personal license of Unity 2) you can make a unity project for browser/webGL and use a browser in the android app to open that (like what Cordova does).

Comment: Given Unity's new networking API, it's not that hard to not rely on Android's API for networking, so I would recommend building a Unity app, not an Android/Java app that has Unity embedded. (Of course my experience with Unity is greater than it is with native andr apps, so I am biased)

Comment: @K.Gkinis Thanks alot!